# How to solve an exponential equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods, exponential-function

I would like to  solve the following equation to find *Q.*

$Q+{q \left( {{\rm e}^{{\frac {{\it nb}\,{\it nv}\,\ t\,q}{a-bu+q
 \left( \ t+\beta \right) }}}}-1 \right)  \left( 1-{{\rm e}^{{
\frac {Q\ t\,q}{ \left( a-bu+q \left( \ t+\beta \right) 
 \right) p}}}} \right)  \left( 1-{{\rm e}^{{\frac {\ t\,q}{a-bu+q
 \left( \ t+\beta \right) }}}} \right) ^{-1} \left( 1-{{\rm e}^{{
\frac {{\it nv}\,\ t\,Qq}{ \left( a-bu+q \left( \ t+\beta
 \right)  \right) p}}}} \right) ^{-1}}=0$

Where *p*, *a*, *b*, *t* and ${\beta}$ are positive parameters, and *nb* and *nv* are integer parameters.

${q > 0}$ and ${u > 0}$ are variables.

I have solved the above equation using Taylor series expansion. Indeed, I would like to know whether it is possible to find a numerical solution (please note that *q* and *u* are also variable and I don't know their exact value)? Or are there any other methods?

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless there is some trick, this would be absolutely disgusting to work out. You need a computer.